# Incrementing and decrementing value during do while loop in Parking

Tags: java

While I am design the parking system, I am struggling with increment and decrement value.
For example, 
If I type rT, the large number will decrement once.
After I choose that again, it's not decrementing anymore.

Can someone body explain it to me, thanks?

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class challenge3 {

    private static int small = 9;
    private static int  medium = 24;
    private static int mediumHandi = 5;
    private static int  large = 10;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        handiCar hc = new handiCar();
        rTruck rT = new rTruck();
        rCar rC = new rCar();
        handiTruck hT = new handiTruck();
        bike b = new bike();

        int p = 48;

        String parkagain = "";
        do {

            System.out.println("Type your vehicle type: " +
                    "handiCar hc " +
                    "rTruck rT " +
                    "rCar rC" +
                    "handiTruck hT " +
                    "bike b ");
            String s1 = scanner.nextLine();

           if (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("hc")) {
               mediumHandi--;
               System.out.println("Thank you.");
               if (mediumHandi == 0) {
                   System.out.println("Sorry the parking space has run out");

               }

           }
           else if (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("rT")) {
               large--;
               System.out.println("Thank you.");
               if (large == 0) {
                   System.out.println("Sorry the parking space has run out");

               }

           } else if (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("rC")) {
               medium--;
               System.out.println("Thank you.");
               if (medium == 0) {
                   System.out.println("Sorry the parking space has run out");

               }

           } else if (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("hT")) {
               large--;
               System.out.println("Thank you.");
               if (large == 0) {
                   System.out.println("Sorry the parking space has run out");

               }

           } else if (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
               small--;
               System.out.println("Thank you.");
               if (small == 0) {
                   System.out.println("Sorry the parking space has run out");

               }

           }


            System.out.println("Number of small parking " + small);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Number of large parking " + large);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Number of medium parking "+medium);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Number of handi meduim " + mediumHandi);
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Type your vehicle type: " +
                    "handiCar hc " +
                    "rTruck rT " +
                    "rCar rC" +
                    "handiTruck hT " +
                    "bike b or no ");
            parkagain = scanner.next();

       }while (
               (parkagain.equalsIgnoreCase("rT") ||
                parkagain.equalsIgnoreCase("hc")||
                parkagain.equalsIgnoreCase("rC")||
                parkagain.equalsIgnoreCase("hT")||
                parkagain.equalsIgnoreCase("b") ||
                       p <= 48 )

        );

        System.out.println("Thank you!");
        scanner.close();
    }

    public static class handiTruck {

    }

    public static class rTruck {


    }

    public static class rCar {


    }

    public static class handiCar {
    }

    public static class bike {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are displaying the same prompt message at the end of the loop and have `scanner.next()` which will not consider new line. Remove that and assign `s1` to `parkagain`. it should work fine

Replace

```
System.out.println("Type your vehicle type: " +
                    "handiCar hc " +
                    "rTruck rT " +
                    "rCar rC" +
                    "handiTruck hT " +
                    "bike b or no ");
parkagain = scanner.next();
```

at the end of the loop with this

```
parkagain = s1
```